# Help understanding Isothermal titration calorimetry ITC

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium, enzyme-kinetics, calorimetry

Trying to understand Isothermal titration calorimetry: ITC , from a public online forum ([Off-topic question related to ITC binding studies](https://www.jiscmail.ac.uk/cgi-bin/wa-jisc.exe?A2=ind2208&L=CCP4BB&O=D&P=51713)) I got this question:

We performed an ITC binding study (using Affinity ITC, TA Instruments) to evaluate protein-DNA interaction which resulted in a perfect sigmoidal curve. We used the ‘one set of sites’ binding algorithm (“independent” model) for curve fitting and to calculate binding and thermodynamic parameters. The study suggested two copies of the protein binding to a single duplex DNA, i.e., the stoichiometry of protein:DNA is 2:1 (N=2). The ITC calculated the KD (equilibrium molar dissociation constant) in μM (micromolar). But the reviewer is asking to report the KD in (micromolar)^2 instead of micromolar mentioning that the binding reaction is 2A + B <-> (A2)B and the complex is (A2)B and not AB. Though we're trying to explain to the reviewer that we couldn't find any software that can compute the KD in (micromolar)^2 for the stoichiometry of 2 but he is not agreeing to it. We have used the NanoAnalyze software from the TA instrument. This software does not have a model to measure the KD in (micromolar)^2.

I would be grateful if you could help me to resolve this problem or at least let me know what explanation might be appropriate to answer the reviewer’s concern that it’s a general practice to report the KD in the Molar irrespective of stoichiometry

ADDENDUM:
Based on the curve fit, we also believe that the two proteins bind independently to the DNA duplex with the same affinity. The DNA indeed contains 2 sites for protein binding. As far as the dimerization of protein is concerned, we have already confirmed, through different approaches, that the protein doesn't behave as a dimer in the solution.

Comment: @Poutnik would you be so kind to create the Isothermal titration calorimetry or ITC tag ? Cant edit equation right know, running from tablet, old too, it ll be on my to do list for this forum

Comment: I am not sure if it is a good idea to create a tag until there are multiple cases of the ITC topic. I suppose using the general `calorimetry` is OK, having 31 cases total, 3 this year.

Comment: It might help if you post some real or mock data and fit parameters, and the figure for the fit, as an example so that readers that want to can check the problem.

Comment: @BuckThorn any free package that can run simulation with models thatt could suit the question above ? First time I read a lot about ITC but not sure their question is right. To me sounds like the DNA ligand could be the titrate with 2 binding site and the protein the titrant so could use the 1:2 model identical sites Association of a monovalent ligand with a bivalent receptor having two identical sites  of Affimeter software suite, but dont have the software available

Comment: @BuckThorn, its not my question I just came accross it and was trying to understand it. All I knew about ITC was about the basic 1:1N=1 model to calculate kd 1/ka

Comment: @BuckThorn I found a free package to analyze ITC experiments: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/full/10.1021/acs.biochem.7b01264 , https://pytc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. Any free source of dataset example to be analyzed ??

Comment: @user836049 have you tried looking within the package itself? Often they bundle test data to verify that it works as it claims.

Comment: @BuckThorn I looked at it didnt find them. Problem is reads only .DH files or out of NITPIC : " The user provides files that hold the heat per injection for each experiment, determined by integrating raw power curves using the instrument software or an alternative such as NITPIC. " BUt what gets me mad is that wasnt able to find anything about .DH file format. Tried to get it from pytc code but wasnt able to find where and how it reads the .DH file

Comment: well found some .DH files into : https://github.com/harmslab/pytc-demos/tree/master/ca-edta that is a  a collection of demo jupyter notebooks that show how to use the pytc API to fit Isothermal Titration Calorimetry experiments.  .. Dont have jupiter (dont even know what is it but now I have some .DH examples